# Checking in four directions for board game win

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have the following code which I would like to simplify in Haskell, although I'm not sure how. I recall that I can use monads to simplify a case chain when the result of the case leads onto a next bit of code but in my example, I return from the function when I get a value, and continue to the next bit of code if I don't get a value (`Nothing`).

```
checkWon :: Board -> Maybe Col
checkWon board = let moves = pieces board
                     n     = target board
                     col   = snd (moves !! 0) in
    case east moves col n of
        Just c  -> Just c
        Nothing ->
            case west moves col n of
                Just c -> Just c
                Nothing ->
                    case north moves col n of
                        Just c -> Just c
                        Nothing ->
                            case south moves col n of
                                Just c -> Just c
                                Nothing -> Nothing
```

The only other thing I've tried is using `if` statements where I calculate all the values of the functions before-hand and test against them in a `if`-`else` branch; but this still feels verbose. Is there any syntactic sugar in Haskell to simplify this, or is my current solution the best option? Maybe I would need to structure my code so I don't fall into this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question! This is a little trickier than the usual “clean up a string of `Maybe`s” in that you want short-circuiting on the `Just` case, and continued computation on `Nothing`. There is—of course—a function for that. Skip to the bottom for the answer, or read through for how you might find or derive it.

## Finding the Answer

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). Pretty much always Hoogle. Think about what you've got and what you need, then start testing types against Hoogle. In this case you've got a sequence of `Maybe a` values that you want to reduce to a single value. The key insight is that the sequence *must* all be of the same `Maybe a` type, so it's possible (and thus probably necessary) to create a list (an actual `[Maybe a]`) of them. Thus our candidate type signature—

```
? :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
```

[Pop that type signature into Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BMaybe%20a%5D%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a) and the very first thing that comes up is—

```
-- "base" Control.Monad
-- | This generalizes the list-based concat function.
msum :: MonadPlus m => [m a] -> m a
```

Test it in GHCi and—

```
> msum [Nothing, Just 1, Just 2]
Just 1
> msum [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
Just 1
> msum [Nothing] :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

Yep, that's what we want.

## Deriving the Answer

There are probably two different ways you might come up with your own solution. Either start at the concrete and generalize, or cobble a solution from typeclasses down.

### From the Concrete

Consider again the type of the function you need.

```
? :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
```

A no-frills solution to this with primitive recursion and pattern matching should be self-obvious (or will be with experience).

```
firstJust :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
firstJust []             = Nothing
firstJust (Nothing:ms)   = firstJust ms
firstJust (j@(Just _):_) = j
```

From there we can deploy our usual bag of <s>tricks</s> higher-order functions to write this more idiomatically.

```
firstJust :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
firstJust = foldr orElse Nothing
    where
        orElse :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
        orElse Nothing    m = m
        orElse j@(Just _) _ = j
```

Now a few facts may percolate to the top of your brain and strike you as insight.

1. `Maybe` encapsulates a notion of “failure”.
2. `orElse` provides an alternative value in the case of failure.
3. [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) is a typeclass that exists.

So we get a spiffy one-liner—

```
firstJust :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
firstJust = foldr (<|>) Nothing
```

### From the Typeclass Down

This all depends on which tools you're most familiar with. If you're a `Monoid` fan and used to relying on newtypes you may recognize the pattern of condensing a list of values as `Control.Monoid.mconcat`. Then you just need to write or choose an appropriate `Monoid` instance, and of course if you're really on top of the ball you'll know that [one already exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First).

```
import Control.Monoid
import Data.Coerce (coerce) -- GHC 7.8.1

firstJust :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
firstJust = getFirst . mconcat . coerce
-- Compatible with older GHC but slower, `getFirst . mconcat . map First`
```

## Just the Answer

This version relies on `MonadPlus`, which ties up all of the other concepts we used and provides various handy functions to leverage their combined power. This version is as terse as it's gonna get.

```
import Control.Monad (msum) -- Or, Control.Applicative.asum

checkWon :: Board -> Maybe col
checkWon board = msum [ east moves col n
                      , west moves col n
                      , north moves col n
                      , south moves col n
                      ]
    where
        moves = pieces board
        n     = target board
        col   = snd (moves !! 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to use a monad, the Maybe monad wouldn't be the right choice for this logic.  Your logic uses `Nothing` as a signal to keep going; the Maybe monad uses it as a signal to stop.

It's a little difficult to follow the code, because I don't know the types of a lot of things.  I'm going to assume that east/west/north/south are functions that take `moves`, `col`, and `n` as arguments.

Assuming I've guessed correctly, you can do this: `map (\dir -> dir moves col n) [east, west, north, south]`